# GTK# Ask monitor boundaries

Tags: c#, mono, gtk, monodevelop, gtk#

I'm developing an application for audio cuesheet. Inside the application I save position, height and width if user closes the application, so that on start I can reset the position, height and width. 
Now I got a bug report, that on 2 monitors, the user closes the application, switches to only 1 monitor (docking out notebook) and opens the application again, the application is not seen anymore, since the position was on the second monitor (x,y > 2000px).
Do you have an idea, how I could ask GTK for monitor boundaries?
The code I use:
Setting position:

```
this.Move(Program.getInstance().getObjOption().getIntWindowX(), Program.getInstance().getObjOption().getIntWindowY());
```

Getting position:

```
protected void OnDeleteEvent(object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
{
            //Save window allocation
            int intX;
            int intY;
            this.GetPosition(out intX, out intY);
            Program.getInstance().getObjOption().setIntWindowX(intX);
            Program.getInstance().getObjOption().setIntWindowY(intY);
}
```

Thanks for your help!
Sven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are after total screen size of connected monitors this can be obtained by

```
 Gdk.Screen screen = Gdk.Screen.Default;
 int width = screen.Width; 
 int height = screen.Height;
```

I just tried it with 2 monitors connected (1920x1200 & 1920x1080)
It gave 3840x1200

Comment: Thank you, that was perfect :)!